# JavaScript YouTube API play video while other paused - multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I got the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdUTy/), which basically has 2 imgs and 2 iframes.
each img and iframe are in a different div (as pair).

the iframe is hidden while the img is not.
When you click on the img, the img disappear, and the iframe become visible instead (**and starts immediately to play the video**)

if I click on the second img, the first one should be visible again instead of the iframe, **and the video should pause, while the video of the second one starts to play**

my fiddle above works as I want just for the first 2 occurrences, after that I get an error:

```
Error: TypeError: player.pauseVideo is not a function
```

and the video doesnt play.

desperate for help, tried for about 7 hours with no luck.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the player when click on the img, then check if player exist for this img, if exist play the existent

```
if (typeof players[index] == 'undefined') {
    players.push(new YT.Player(iframe[0], {
        events: {
            'onReady': function (event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }
        }
    }));
} else {
    players[index].seekTo(0).playVideo();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdUTy/2/)